# Multiple Displays option not showing on Android Emulator 29.2.0 update

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-10.0

Recently **Emulator 29.2.0 Stable** released. Here is the related document https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2019/09/emulator-2920-stable.html.

After the update, my Emulator is not showing the `Displays` option in Emulator as mentioned in the docs above.

As per the document, I have created an emulator with `Android 10 (Q)`.

Here is the screenshot.

[image]

> **Note:** Invalidate and Restart is not working. Already tried that.

Comment: I have used Pixel3a as device and APi 29 (android 10) as sdk. It has display option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried with multiple system images of 29 api level and came to know that, the **Display** tab is only visible with the image with **API level 29**. Even after creating emulator with image of **Q** is not working.

For more check below screenshot to get more idea.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes with the answer of **@pRaNaY** I just checked that is it working with `x86 and x86_64 ABI image file`?

And yes it is only **working with API 29 with `x86 and x86_64 ABI image file`**.

**But it is not display in `Android(Q)`**

[image]