# Cant setup app in multiple displays size as android 3.6

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

When Android 3.6 released it came out with a big feature, the Multi-display support display dimensions from the Emulator

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/#multi-display_support

But in my emulator, I cant find that option, I have updated all and nothing

[image]

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/q/57991447/1343788

Answer (score 0):

The multi display settings menu is displayed only if you are running the Android 10 image API level 29.