# Mutliple display option not present on Android Emulator with API 29

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I need to emulate an external display.

I get it with:

```
fun getSecondDisplay(context: Context): Display? {
    val displayManager = context.getSystemService(Context.DISPLAY_SERVICE) as DisplayManager
    if (displayManager.displays == null || displayManager.displays.size <= 1) {
        return null
    }
    // We take the first additional screen
    return displayManager.displays[1]
}
```

Dispalys option is not present in "Extended controls" :
[image]

Here is my config:
[image]

I had a look at this post [Multiple Displays option not showing on Android Emulator 29.2.0 update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57991447/multiple-displays-option-not-showing-on-android-emulator-29-2-0-update) but doesn't help me

It works with a same "Nexus 10" emulator config on API 30 :(

Answer (score 0):

Emulator with x86_64 , extended control "Displays" not visible.

Emulator with x86, extended control "Displays" **is** visible.